# Is it possible to use webpack and hot rebuild in a PHP legacy app?

Tags: javascript, php, webpack, rebuild

Usually with hot rebuild or hot reload you assume an index.html file in the same folder (or in a dist/ folder), but what if the entry point to the site is another app, like a legacy PHP app? Is it still possible to rebuild whatever module or component you're working on, and make the server reload the page? Reload is not as important as automatic rebuild, though.

Comment: looking for this too